# How can i achieve following heirachy using autolayout?

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout

I did some of demos of scrollview with autolayout. I have used only one view in them, but in this case I want to use multiple `UIViews` so that I can meet my requirements. I am doing this task for guided tours. I tried doing this with multiple views but it doesn’t work.

```
UIScrollView
-uiview1
-uiview2
-uiview3
-uiview4
-uiview5
```

Comment: its best to put all the views inside one container view that sits inside the scrollview, so you can size the container to the correct size for your content, otherwise the scrollview tries to expand all your multiple views which is usually what you dont want.

Comment: You mean to put containerView Inside scrollview and 5 views Inside container view
UIScrollView
-ContainerView
—uiview1
—uiview2
—uiview3
—uiview4
—uiview5

Comment: yeah exactly like that, because putting many views with autolayouts directly into a scrollview can cause you a few headaches with content sizing, so if they all inside one view you can control the size easier. i suggest putting an equal width constraint between the container view and the scrollview for staters

Comment: Not working yet. can you please provide code :(